# How to create vertical seperator between controls on an outlook command bar?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I am creating an outlook 2003 addin which adds some dropdown and button on each mail item opened.I have created a command bar and have added the controls to that command bar . But if i look at the standard tool bar on mail message, each button is seperated by a vertical bar but in my tool bar there is no seperator. How can i create the vertical seperator between controls on my command bar. I am using VSTO 2005SE and C# for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to put a seperator between controls-set the button's BeginGroup property to true. This property puts a vertical bar at the begining of the control so if the button is the first control on menu bar, this seperator won't be visible but if this is a second control on bar, a vertical bar will be placed before second control.